# Comparison between class + (void)method in Objective-c and The scope operator :: in c++

Tags: c++, objective-c

I'm coming from the Objective-C world and learning some C++ to integrate box2D to my apps. I discovered the `class::function` syntax in C++ and I was wondering if it compare to a class method but I saw the same method called once with `::` and once with `->`. Is there any equivalent to a class method in C++?

Comment: If by class method you mean a method that can be called without a class instance, then the equivalent would be a `static` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the declaration of your question doesn't match its definition, but let me try to enlighten you anyway...

> Comparison between class `+ (void)method` in Objective-C and the scope operator `::` in C++

They aren't quite the same. C++ has namespaces, so `NameSpace::func()` means "call function named `func` residing in namespace `NameSpace`".

**It is also used for calling static member functions,** but that is not its **only** purpose.

> Is there any equivalent to a class method in c++?

Yes, as I just wrote: `static` class members belong to the class, not to an instance of a class.

Comment: and also `::func()` calls the function from the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any equivalent to a class method in c++?

Yes, simple use the static method like this:

```
class MyClass 
{
public:
    static void classFunc() { }
};

 MyClass::classFunc();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `::` is the so-called "`scope-operator`", you use it for example, to call static methods from C++-classes.
The "`->`"-Operator is used to dereference members of a pointer-to-object (members and methods alike).

For a reference there is [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) and also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator) article:

> In computer programming, scope is an enclosing context where values and expressions are associated. The scope resolution operator helps to identify and specify the context to which an identifier refers. The specific uses vary across different programming languages with the notions of scoping. In many languages the scope resolution operator is written ::.

```
class A
{         //
  static int i;  //scope of A
};        //
A::i = 4; //scope operator refers to the integer i declared
```